# Magento checkout buttons gone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, checkout

I have a problem with my Magento 1.9 CE webshop.
When you order products the next button is not showing up on the checkout page, nor orders can be placed.

Things i have tried so far:

- I installed a one page checkout plugin to see if this will work, it doesn't. 
  When you click on the "Place order now" button it rederects back to the one page chekout overview page.
- I uninstalled all 3rd party plugins via magentoconnect, still no succes.
- used the default theme to check if the checkout process will go true, also no succes.
- used the original prototype.js file, because via firebug i noticed some errors on this file. also no succes.

i have been googling for 4 days now trying to search for a solution, but i cannot find the problem, there are a lot of solutions for checkout problems but none of them seem to work or are simmilar to my issue. 
Is there annyone who can maybe help me out?

I also have a cookie notice when visiting the site, can also not click on agree to make it dissapear, i have a feeling this is related to the checkout problem.

The URL of the webshop is: https://www.pepstore.nl

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: To use jQuery, make sure it's called only once on the page (looks like it's called twice), followed by noConflict (which you have), and then your jquery files. Also, then make all jquery files use $j instead of $. Doing these steps should clear up some of your errors off the bat.

Comment: @kaska thank you for the quick reply but i do not understand what you mean by it is called twice, which file is doing that?

Comment: When I go to your site and view source it shows that jquery-1.10.2.min.js is there twice. So I'd suggest you find the layout xml file that is adding the second one on the page (productyoutubevideo) and comment out the line that is adding the jquery. Either that or there may be in the custom extension (productyoutube perhaps) in admin->system config there is an option to disable jquery for this extension.

Comment: @kaska thank you very very much, it was the **** youtube video plugin, this was edited to make it work so i disabled it when trying to figure out which plugin is causing the issue, i have removed it via magento connect and everything works fine!! i feel really stupid right now